# Adding image in header in Jquery

Tags: jquery, image, header

I want to set a image in my header in Jquery. Here is my source code

```
that.setLanguageViewHeader = function() {

    str =   that.getRole();
    str +=  '<h2>The Unit</h2>' +
            '<ul>' +
            '  <li><a id="navMyAccount" >My Account</a><span>|</span></li>' +
            '</ul>' +
            '<div class="clearbth"></div>';
    $('#loggedInHeader').html(str);

};
```

Noe here i want to set a image instead of my account link. PLease tell me how to do that

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
$('#loggedInHeader').html('<img src="..." />');
```